# Is it possible to embed a dynamic react component into a separate html file without downloading a file or using a server?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, widget

I am using React to make a SPA where you can customize a component (font size, color, etc) and then embed the customized component into a website. Is there a way to bundle the component and express it as HTML where the user can simply copy and paste it into their website?

I have tried using iframes, but it is fetching data from a URL. I'd like to avoid this if possible since the module/component/widget needs to be copy/pasted.

I have also thought about using webpack to bundle the component using the UMD library target, but I can't find a way to bundle the file in realtime- where it includes the user's customizations.

Lastly, I have thought about rendering a html string which is about as close as I have got to what I want, but it does not include any styles.

This is what the component I am trying to make universally modular looks like:

```
        <LinearLayoutDiv>
            <ModuleHeader />
            <ModuleStoryDiv>
            {[...Array(numStories)].map((val, index) => {
                const data = generateFakeArticle();
                return <ModuleStory
                    key={`module-story-${orientation}-${index}`}
                    picture={data.picture}
                    summary={data.summary}
                    distance={data.distance}
                    author={data.author}
                    orientation={orientation} />
            })}
            </ModuleStoryDiv>
            <ModuleFooter />
        </LinearLayoutDiv>
```

I am using styled components and a theme provider to pass user customizations down to the component.

How should I go about doing this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried renderToStaticMarkup? https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup

Comment: Yeah I have, but I wasn't able to transfer the styles over.  I think this is the right direction, but I am not sure how to convert the styles into a style tag so that they can be copy/pasted over.. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

How I ended up doing it was like so:

There are two parts I need to create a fully modular widget: HTML and CSS.

I am using styled components. So to get the CSS, I used their secret internal stylesheet to get all the styles of my application. This part is inefficient since I have no way of telling which CSS belongs to the module and which CSS is part of my application so it just takes all of the CSS. Now I have a CSS stylesheet that can be embedded in a style tag.

```
import { __DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_HAUNTED_BY_SPOOKY_GHOSTS as scSecret } from 'styled components';

const CSS = scSecret.StyleSheet.instance.tags.map(tag => tag.css()).join('')
```

To get the HTML I made the top most component of the module into a secondary root, and used .outerHTML to get the HTML of itself and its children.

```
document.getElementById('secondary-root').outerHTML
```

With both the HTML and CSS I can create a simple HTML doc that can be copy pasted into a separate website.